# perform search from database according to letters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I have a search form that helps the user to search anything from the database.

View of table is (Name of table = menu)

```
id  dish
1   ABC
2   CDE
3   EFG
4   CDF
```

At present when user enters a word e.g ABC and then perform the search using the form, i get the desired result, but i wish to change this functionality a bit,

i want that if the user enters first letter eg: C then all the words in the table dish that have letter C in it should get displayed,

then if he types eg: CD then all the words that have CD together should get displayed. Can anyone please tell me how to do so

index.php page code that contains search form:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#form').on('submit', function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 't_searchmenu.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: {text:$('#textbox').val()},
                    success: function(response) {
                    $('#prod_search').html(response);
                    }
                });
            });
    });
</script>

<form class="pull-right" style="width:100%;" id="form" >
    <input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" style="width:80%;" />
    <button type="submit" value="submit" id="generate2"  class="btn btn-primary">Find</button>
</form>
```

Code on t_searchmenu.php page

```
 $t = $_POST['text']; 
 $sql = " SELECT * from menu where dish='" . $t . "'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         //print the result
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do query like this:

```
$sql=" SELECT * from menu where dish like '%".$t."%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`%` wildcard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html). It matches 0 or more characters. For example `C%` would match `CDE`, `CEF`, and so on. `CD%` would match `CDE`, `CDF`, etc:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM menu WHERE dish LIKE '$t%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
SELECT * from tableName 
WHERE columnName LIKE '%".$t."%'";
```